# How to convert my url using .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I know there are lot of questions in stackoverflow But none is working
I want to convert this url

```
http://localhost/livelor/profile.php?u=nane
```

To

```
http://localhost/livelor/nane
```

And i Want to remove My php extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure this is totaly correct. But in basic this is code in your .htacess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  /livelor/(.*)$   /livelor/profile.php?u=$1
```

More information and tutorial
https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: @Kelvin: What is `RewriteUrl`?